# Changing password of Unix remote server through PHP SSH

Tags: php, unix, ssh, passwords

I am attemping to use the phpseclib to change the password of my remote server through its NET_SSH2 functions. Below is what I am using.

```
    <?php
    require_once('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('server1.server.com');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $ssh->write("passwd\n");
    $ssh->read('(current) UNIX Password:');
    $ssh->write("oldpass\n");
    $ssh->read('New password:');
    $ssh->write("newpass\n");
    $ssh->read('Retype new password:');
    $ssh->write("newpass\n");
    echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');

    ?>
```

Everytime my script just hangs and doesn't seem to do much of anything. Anything I could be doing wrong here?

Here is the documentation on this:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html

Comment: If you run your program under `strace(1)`, what are the exact strings that it _does_ read? Why don't you wait for the initial shell prompt? If you add debugging `echo` statements, where exactly does it stall?

Comment: Turns out I capitalized a single p letter. Works like a charm now. Thanks for your detailed response either way.

Comment: @user1328041 if you yourself found and answer, then feel free to delete the question so others won't read it

Comment: @user1328041: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it.

Comment: You need "$ssh->read" before "$ssh->write". I posted code below.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('sudo passwd root');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

You can execute any linux command through `shell_exec` function

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
    if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
    $ssh->write("passwd\n");
    echo $ssh->read('(current) UNIX password:');
    $ssh->write("oldpassword\n");
    echo $ssh->read('New UNIX password:');
    $ssh->write("newpassword\n");
    echo $ssh->read('Retype new UNIX password:');
    $ssh->write("newpassword\n");
    echo $ssh->read('passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.');

?>
```